# Multiple Audio codecs in ALSA

Tags: linux, alsa

I have one query regarding ALSA codec registration. I need to connect two Audio codecs to two I2S interfaces of Host. Both Audio codecs are connected separately to each I2S interface.

Can someone point to some link or reference implementation for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For editing configuration and all , you can refer 
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293450/alsa-send-audio-to-two-audio-devices this link. But for that, your I2S driver should support multiple devices.

Comment: Thanks for useful info. But Actually my question is different.
How to connect two audio codecs to two different  I2S bus?
Should i use two cards or a single card can contain multiple codec?